# Postman getting random UserName inside Pre-Request Scripts

Tags: javascript, api, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I'm wanting to generate a random user to be created using the API, every time I run the request.

I have an email environment variable which I want to be set to a random email every time the user create request is sent.

**I currently have:**

```js
pm.environment.set("Email", pm.globals.get("$randomUserName") + "@myDomain.co.uk");
```

I'm wanting to get a [random user name](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables-list/) from `$randomUserName`

**However**, I can't seem to find out how to get a value from $randomUserName in the Pre-Request Scripts section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `.replaceIn()` method in the sandbox.

You could do something like this:

```
let userName = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomUserName}}")
pm.environment.set("Email", `${userName}_${Date.now()}@myDomain.co.uk`)
```

More info can be found here:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmvariables